# Generating Unique Usernames in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database

I am curious how people are handling the following situation. Let's say we have a Users Table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
[UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ProfileId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[UserTypeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[UserName] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Password] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Salt] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[ActivationCode] [char](8) NULL,
[InvalidLoginAttempts] [int] NOT NULL,
[IsLockedOut] [int] NOT NULL,
[LastLoginDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[Active] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[LastUpdated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
```

So here is my actual question. Previously when using int for the PK I could insert a user and autocreate a username based on the identity insert if the user did not supply a username. Example of why this would happen. "OpenId Registration for instance" So how would one generate a unique "count" so to say using guids. I certainly don't want to display "welcome userXXX-XXX-XXX and so on.

My thoughts are maybe build a seperate table for this with and int IDENTITY and store the guid in there??

Comment: The part which says `Example of why this would happen. "OpenId Registration for instance"` is not clear.

Comment: I don't require an e-mail address for my OPenId Registration. Similar to StackOverflow so I need to autocreate some sort of string value to identify the internal user account I create for them behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes, I see. Well, I starred it and I will be curious to read about the solution to this problem.

Comment: Mike, this looks interesting http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/sql-server-denali-sequence-object.html

Comment: I remember something like that from DB2

Comment: That sequence object is interesting, but it is not clear from the article whether it can guarantee unique values in a scenario where instancing is used.

Comment: True, I am researching that as well. May need to post a specific SO question about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add another column with identity to the table and use that.
Or pick a random number, check if userName already exists, if so generate a new.

Comment: Multiple DB Instances :) Would create more problems

Comment: Magnus, I answered the same half an hour ago, and then as soon as I realized the problem, I deleted my answer before anyone would downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Following Magnus's proposal, you could build a default user name by concatenating an additional int/autonumber field in the table + the server's name (or the database name), or part of it as!

Suppose that you have SERV1, SERV2, SERV3 running. You could then either build the default user name as userSERVX_Y, or userSERVX0000Y, etc. Your username building scheme will depend on your server naming strategy. If your server names are not 'sexy'enough, you could add somwehere a table with aliases for your servers.